# How to set one active class for every block? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, function

I have a Bootstrap layout: a container, a row, several "block-divs" and three divs for every block-div.
The number of block-divs is dynamically created by a script (the user choose how many blocks will be shown on the page), but every block contains three divs.

When the user click on a div, an active class is added to it. 
My problem is that my code will set only one active class in the entire page but I want to set one active class for every block.

How can I achieve that without using any JS framework (only pure JavaScript)?

I leave you an example of my layout: https://jsfiddle.net/9vr92ss4/

```js
var myCol = document.getElementsByClassName('myCol');

function getTarget(e) {
  if (!e) {
    e = window.event;
  }
  return e.target || e.srcElement;
}

function setActive(e) {
  var target = getTarget(e);
  for (i = 0; i < myCol.length; i++) {
   myCol[i].className = 'col-xs-4 myCol';
  }
  
  target.className = 'col-xs-4 myCol active';
}

for (j = 0; j < myCol.length; j++) {
  myCol[j].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    setActive(e);
  }, false);
}
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.myCol {
  padding: 40px 0;
  border: 1px solid #F44336;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.active {
  background: #9C27B0;
  border: 1px solid #9C27B0;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-xs-12 block">
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">a-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">b-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">c-1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 block">
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">a-2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">b-2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">c-2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 block">
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">a-3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">b-3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">c-3</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So do you want to set an active class on many blocks with one click or that with each click you can set the class and it would not be removed?

Comment: jQuery is the hard dependency for Bootstrap. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas I want to set a div with an active class on the first block, a div with an active class on the second block and so on. Only one div with an active class for every block. If a block already has a div with an active class and I click another div, the new div clicked will have the active class and the old one will lose it.

Comment: @LiXinyang I need pure JS, the fact is that I'm using bootstrap just to try it, I'm new to JS and I have yet to start studying jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actively resetting the class names with this:

```
for (i = 0; i < myCol.length; i++) {
  myCol[i].className = 'col-xs-4 myCol';
}
```

You need to check whether the parent node of `myCol` is the same as the parent node of `target`:

```
function setActive(e) {
  var target = getTarget(e),
      section = target.parentNode;

  for (i = 0; i < myCol.length; i++) {
    if (myCol[i].parentNode === section) {
      myCol[i].className = 'col-xs-4 myCol';
    }
  }

  target.className = 'col-xs-4 myCol active';
}
```

See this updated working snippet:

```js
var myCol = document.getElementsByClassName('myCol');

function getTarget(e) {
  if (!e) {
    e = window.event;
  }
  return e.target || e.srcElement;
}

function setActive(e) {
 var target = getTarget(e),
      section = target.parentNode;
  
  for (i = 0; i < myCol.length; i++) {
    if (myCol[i].parentNode === section) {
      myCol[i].className = 'col-xs-4 myCol';
    }
  }
  
  target.className = 'col-xs-4 myCol active';
}

for (j = 0; j < myCol.length; j++) {
  myCol[j].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    setActive(e);
  }, false);
}
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.myCol {
  padding: 40px 0;
  border: 1px solid #F44336;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.active {
  background: #9C27B0;
  border: 1px solid #9C27B0;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-xs-12 block">
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">a-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">b-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">c-1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 block">
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">a-2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">b-2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">c-2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 block">
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">a-3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">b-3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">c-3</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that he wants to mark just one element for every block.

Comment: mh, you're probably right. wasn't really clear from the question

Comment: updated my question and the fiddle to make it work "radio button style". ;)

Comment: @Connum this is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you very much, it was so simple. Now I need to understand how and why it works ahah.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **much** simplier solution, but with using **`jQuery`**.

```js
$('.myCol').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.myCol').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.myCol {
  padding: 40px 0;
  border: 1px solid #F44336;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.active {
  background: #9C27B0;
  border: 1px solid #9C27B0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 block">
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">a-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">b-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">c-1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 block">
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">a-2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">b-2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">c-2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 block">
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">a-3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">b-3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 myCol">c-3</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the problem by thinking one row at the time.

You are doing a good job. The only thing you need is a data structure that stores the state of your grid.